# Maven : Exclude Submodule with Wildcards

Tags: maven, command-line-interface

I want to exclude a submodule from a maven build via maven CLI. (I dont need a  pom.xml configuration solution, it needs to be via maven CLI).

So in order to **include** a submodule in maven I can use the following command

```
mvn clean install -pl module-1
```

I can also **exclude** a certain maven module with

```
mvn clean install -pl !module-2
```

I can **include with wildcards**
mvn clean install -pl **modules

How can I negate that? How can I exclude with wildcards?

```
mvn clean install -pl !**modules
```

=> is not working.

Any solutions?